# RadChart - How to use it dynamicatlly, not in HTML

Tags: angular, nativescript, radchart

I am currenlty working on a cross platform native mobile app for Android & iOS using NativeScript & Angular. I am using [RadChart](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/Chart/overview) as a charting engine.

But i want to use these charts dynamically, not in html. I am not able to find any suitable example regarding the same. Even on the documentation, it's not available.

Also i have used RadChart in html, it's working for me. But in Android, i am not getting animation, for iOS i can see the animation. Please help me to find the solution.

Additionally, is there any other solution available for cross platform native chart engine in NativeScript & Angular ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations are supported only on iOS. There is a open [feature request for Android](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/283) already, you may vote and subscribe to the Github issue for further updates.

An [component factory](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) can be used to add components dynamically.